# ssh Match LocalAddress with ssh.socket doesn't work

Tags: ssh, configuration, sshd, sockets

On a new Ubuntu install I noticed that SSH uses sockets to start its daemon on demand. I've configured `/etc/systemd/system/ssh.socket.d/port.conf`, on the server, to listen on two ports as follows:

```
[Socket]
ListenStream=
ListenStream=1234
ListenStream=1235
```

For the SSH server configuration side, I have a custom config file (`/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/root.conf`) as follows:

```
Match LocalAddress 192.168.1.100:1235
  PermitRootLogin yes
```

Where `192.168.1.100` is the IP address of the SSH server. **This configuration does not work**. It seems that `ssh.socket` receives a request at either of the ports above but uses a different (random?) port to send that request to the SSH daemon.

Is there a way to keep using `ssh.socket` and `Match LocalAddress` together? I like the idea of only starting the daemon when a connection request arrives at the socket, so I would rather not disable it

Comment: I'm not sure `LocalAddress` permits a `:port` suffix - have you tried `Match LocalPort 1235` instead? See for example [Is it possible to have sshd accept passwords only on certain ports?](https://serverfault.com/a/637014)

Comment: @steeldriver I assumed you could use the same pattern for LocalAddress as you do for Address, which was a wrong assumption. I do have multiple IPs and wanted to bind to a specific one. Using a combination of LocalPort and LocalAddress did the trick! Feel free to post a full answer so I can accept it